# replacing badge names to words

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
if(!target) {
    message.reply(` Mention a user if you want to find their info. `)
} else {
  
    var member = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id)  

    if (target.flags == "HOUSE_BALANCE") target.flags = "Hypesquad Balance";
    if (target.flags == "HOUSE_BRILLIANCE") target.flags = "Hypesquad Brillance";
    if (target.flags == "HOUSE_BRAVERY") target.flags = "Hypesquad Bravery";
    if (target.flags == "VERIFIED_BOT") target.flags = "Verified Bot";
    let flags = target.flags.toArray()

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Userinfo`) 
        .setColor(`BLUE`)
        .setThumbnail(target.avatarURL({ size: 2048, dynamic: true }))
        .addFields (
            {name: `Username + tag`, value: `` + target.tag, inline: true},
            {name: `Server join date`, value: `` + `${moment.utc(member.joinedAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")} UTC`, inline: true },
            {name: `User creation date`, value: `` + `${moment.utc(target.createdAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")} UTC`, inine: true},
            // {name: `Status`, value: ``+ member.status}
            {name: `Badges`, value: `` + flags, inline: true}
         
          )
    message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})

}
```

I'm trying to get badges from a user. However, it will display like `HOUSE_BALANCE` for any user having the Hypesquad Balance badge, `HOUSE_BRILLANCE` for Hypesquad Brillance, etc. However, I would like to replace those with like `Hypesquad Balance` for Hypesquad Balance badge, `Hypesquad Brillance` for Hypesquad Brillance badge, etc. The code above displays my best try of replacement but was unsuccessfully done. What should I type instead?

Comment: UserFlags is a bitfield. You shouldn't compare them with a string, nor attempt to reassign them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user15517071 said, [`UserFlags`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserFlags) is a [`BitField`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/BitField). You should use the `has` method to check whether a user has a flag/badge.

Note that a user may have multiple flags (e.g. `HOUSE_BRILLIANCE` and `EARLY_VERIFIED_BOT_DEVELOPER`).

The code might look like this:

```js
const badges = []
if (target.flags.has("HOUSE_BALANCE")) badges.push("Hypesquad Balance");
if (target.flags.has("HOUSE_BRILLIANCE")) badges.push("Hypesquad Brilliance");
if (target.flags.has("HOUSE_BRAVERY")) badges.push("Hypesquad Bravery");
if (target.flags.has("VERIFIED_BOT")) badges.push("Verified Bot");

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    // ...
    .addFields (
        // ...
        {name: `Badges`, value: badges.join(', '), inline: true}
    );
```

Alternatively, you could use an object/map to store the badge names of each user flag, and use this to get the badge names of a user:

```js
const flagToBadgeName = {
    HOUSE_BALANCE: "Hypesquad Balance",
    HOUSE_BRILLIANCE: "Hypesquad Brillance",
    HOUSE_BRAVERY: "Hypesquad Bravery",
    VERIFIED_BOT: "Verified Bot"
    // etc
};

const badges = target.flags
    .toArray()
    .map(flag => flagToBadgeName[flag])
    .filter(name => name !== undefined);

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    // ...
    .addFields (
        // ...
        {name: `Badges`, value: badges.join(', '), inline: true}
    );
```